# Instagram API - Can you change users about information ie. websites

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I was wondering whether instagram gives access to account settings where an app could update a users website address?

Comment: Have you checked https://www.instagram.com/developer/ ?

Comment: No, you can't. The API doesn't allow updating user information

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.

Sadly, Instagram API is getting more and more restrictive. Actually, they are going to review every APP ever created in order to approve/disapprove the use of several components:

> Instagram Platform and documentation update. Apps created on or after Nov 17, 2015 will start in Sandbox Mode and function on newly updated API rate-limits and behaviors. Prior to going Live, and being able to be used by people other than the developers of the app, these apps will have to go through a new review process. Please read the API documentation or the Change Log for more details.
>
> Any app created before Nov 17, 2015 will continue to function until
>   June 2016. After June 2016, the app will automatically be moved to
>   Sandbox Mode if it wasn't approved through the review process. The
>   previous version of our documentation is stil available here.

If you want to check what is available to do with their API, just visit this [enpoints link](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/).